# Show date in proper format, from string time to readable date

Tags: php

I want to convert the string `1433669892` to `07-06-2015` (June, 7th, 2015).

For that, I'm using the code:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y',strtotime ($row['order_created']));
```

Where:

```
$row['order_created']= '1433669892'
```

Which is returning:

```
31-12-1969
```

Totally different of what I expected. I know this should be trivial, but I can't  manage to get the right date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', intval( $row['order_created'] ) );
```

The timestamp passed to the function [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) should be an integer as you seem to have in your row.

**Edit** Casting to an integer

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and it works! Do you mean $row['order_created'] is actually an integer?

Comment: No, it's a string, but PHP is not strongly typed, so it will "cast" to a number

Comment: It is converted to an integer, but you can also add `intval($row['order_created'])` if you wich!

Comment: Ok, I got it! This means, I can add days to that date if necessary, right?

Comment: Yes a day = 24*60*60 seconds = 86400